# Conditional breakpoint on mutex not firing

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have a print to stdout function called in multiple threads so I placed a lock on it. The problem is that helgrind reports RACs on the variable that holds the pointer to stdout although the mutex should be locked. My code looks like this:

```
   #ifdef ___USE_DBG
   #define MSG(message) f(message)
   #else 
   #define MSG(message)
   #endif

   void f(message)
   {
       lock(&m1); //lock first observed
       out<<message; //locks held 2 . why? m1 is the only mutex....
       unlock(&m1);
   }
```

I call MSG in different threads with a few debug messages. Obviously I don't get messages when I'm not using a debug build as the function disappears from program. I tried to debug and set a conditional breakpoint on m1._*data.*_lock!=0 but didn't fire. What is the proper way to debug this issue.

Variable names and actual function contents differ.

Also, function is called by both joinable and detached threads.

I have 5 threads that hold/wait mutex m2 and another 5 on m3, each of them within the locked area call MSG(mess). What is the race condition here? Shouldn't each get a it's own turn on MSG because of m1?

```
type1_thread{
    <loop everything until something happens>
    lock(&m2);
    ...
    MSG(something);
    unlock(&m2);
    }

type2_thread{
    <loop everything until something happens>
    lock(&m3);
    ...
    MSG(something_else);
    unlock(&m3);
    }

<start x type1 threads>
<start y type2 threads>
```

I'll edit if further clarification is needed. Actual code is on intranet and far larger.

Comment: Presumably, 'out' already has a lock.

Comment: `out` is a pointer to `std::cout` (code is a bit different)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a double lock in type2_thread, if that can help you, in other hand you have to be sure all mutex are correctly initialized.

```
type2_thread{
    <loop everything until something happens>
    lock(&m3);
    ...
    MSG(something_else);
/////lock(&m3);    
unlock(&m3);
}
```

Comment: It is a typo sorry, it actually is unlock(&m3), I can't copy-paste my code.